# How come a Java Annotation interface overrides methods from the Object Class

Tags: java, interface, annotations

All annotation types in Java automatically extend the Annotation interface. Thus, Annotation is a super interface of all annotations. It is declared within the java.lang.annotation package. It overrides hashCode( ),equals( ), and toString( ), which are defined by Object. But how come an Interface is able to override object methods. An interface must contain only abstract methods, atleast traditional interfaces. So is it supplying some form of implementation?

I visited the source code of The Annotation interface, but all the methods are only declared but not defined. So why overriden

Comment: "It overrides hashCode( ),equals( ), and toString( )", says who?

Comment: I am reading a book, Java the Complete Reference by Herbert Schildt.

Comment: Well that book is wrong then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interface methods cannot "override" methods in a class. Interface methods can only override interface methods in its superinterfaces (see also [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.4.1.1)).

What is happening in `java.lang.annotation.Annotation`, is that `Annotation` just happens to declare `toString`, `hashCode`, and `equals` in its interface body. You can do this when declaring your own interfaces too:

```
interface MyInterface {
    String toString();
    int hashCode();
    boolean equals(Object other);
}
```

This is usually redundant, since all `Object`s have these methods anyway. Presumably, `Annotation` does this to "override" the documentation for these methods, to talk about the behaviour of these methods on an annotation. For example, the documentation for [`hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Annotation.html#hashCode--) describes exactly how a hash code for an annotation is generated.

When you actually get an instance of an annotation with `getAnnotation` for example:

```
SomeAnnotation foo = SomeClass.class.getAnnotation(SomeAnnotation.class);
```

You can inspect `foo.getClass()` and see that it is not `SomeAnnotation`, but some proxy class (in Java 21 at least, probably subject to implementation details) implementing `SomeAnnotation`. After all, you cannot create an instance of an interface.

While annotation interfaces don't override `toString`, `equals` and `hashCode`, you could say that this proxy class returned by `getAnnotation` *does* override them.

Comment: "Interface methods can only override interface methods in its superinterfaces", how is interface able to override methods as it must only contain abstract methods with no body. Btw thanks for the above  explanation

Comment: @RudraShivgan The answer to “how” is just “the Java Language Specification says so”. See the first link in the answer to see the definition of “overriding” an interface method. It’s not just the body that can overridden - a sub interface can change a method’s return type to a more specific type, and more importantly in this case, change the documentation of that method.